# Problema al abrir un pdf desde un webview kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, pdf, webview

tengo este código en kotlin:

```
val webView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.my_webview)
webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
    // Verifica si es .pdf
    if (url.lowercase().endsWith(".pdf")) {
        // Crea un Intent para abrir un archivo con MIME TYPE application/pdf
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "application/pdf")
        try {
            view.context.startActivity(intent)
        } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
            // ¡Error!
           e.printStackTrace()
        }
    } else {  // Si no es .pdf, simplemente carga la URL en el WebView.
        webView.loadUrl(url)
    }
    return true
}
```

}

pero cuando ejecuto mi aplicación al abrir el archivo pdf siempre me muestra error al mostrar pdf en mi app predeterminada para leer pdfs :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que no se puede abrir PDFs en WebView, tal vez ese sea el problema. Por qué no [usas un `Intent`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10530506/13419694)?

Comment: pero estoy intentando que lo redirija externamente a la app predeterminada de lector pdf que tengo instalado en android

Comment: Se tiene que guardar a disco y mediante su URI abrirlo posteriormente

Comment: algún ejemplo de como seria el código?

Comment: Suficiente código en la web de cómo descargar y guardar un archivo en kotlin.